# QueryDef Form not updating

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
If IsNull(SortCriteria) Then
SortCriteria = "ID"
End If

SQL = SQL & " ORDER By " & SortCriteria

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Form_SelectActionsQuery")
qdf.SQL = SQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Form_SelectActionsQuery"

MsgBox "Continue"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Form_SelectActionsQuery", "C:\RTM\TestExcelTransfer", True
MsgBox "All Done. Excel file Created"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form_SelectActionsQuery"
DoCmd.OpenForm "Actions"
```

Above this code I create SQL that varies the search criteria.
All works well on subsequent runs,including creation of Excel file BUT "Form_SelectActionsQuery" does not update or refresh  on screen.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: A query(def) and a form are different things. If you really have both a query and a form with the name `Form_SelectActionsQuery`, this is very confusing and you should change the query name.

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem.  Querydef creates the form. Thanks

Comment: My inexperience - trying to close a non-existent form. Closing the Query is the solution.